# How to link books of series together?

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

[image]

I have to link all the books in series together but I'm not sure.

I have a `SERIES_ID` under which there is a name for a series, author, number of books and number book in the series.

I'm not sure how to have a list of all the other books in a series or at least previous and next book.

So if I had a copy of the 2nd book in a trilogy the first and third book would appear.

Any advice?

Comment: IMHO `NUMBER_BOOK_IN_SERIES` should belong to `BOOK` table.

Comment: @McNets what if a book is in two series?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Then you need a bridge table. But it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your series table is compound. You need to split it up.

```
Series ( series_id, name )
Series_Book ( book_id, series_id, series_ordinal )
```

Now you can easily seek to the series_ordinal-1, series_oridnal+1 for the series. Storing the `count()` as number of books also seems redundant.

Genre and Theme are also pretty nebulous. That method of classification doesn't scale well, or work all that well with humans. Normally you want hierarchical tags, and cloud tags; otherwise, enter "is the Beatles pop or rock?"

Answer (score 0):

As Evan Carroll has pointed out in his comments, if a book can belong to more than one series, you should add a new table to map books and series.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE SERIES (SERIES_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, SERIES VARCHAR(200), NUMBER_OF_BOOKS INT);
> INSERT INTO SERIES VALUES (1, 'Harry Potter', 8)
>
> CREATE TABLE SERIES_BOOKS(SERIES_ID INT, BOOK_ID INT, NUMBER_BOOK_IN_SERIES INT, 
>                           PRIMARY KEY(SERIES_ID, BOOK_ID));
> INSERT INTO SERIES_BOOKS VALUES (1, 1, 1),
>                                 (1, 2, 2),
>                                 (1, 3, 3),
>                                 (1, 4, 4),
>                                 (1, 5, 5),
>                                 (1, 6, 6),
>                                 (1, 7, 7),
>                                 (1, 8, 8);
>
> CREATE TABLE BOOKS (BOOK_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, BOOK VARCHAR(200));
> INSERT INTO BOOKS VALUES (1, 'Harry Potter and the Philosopher''s Stone'),
>                          (2, 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets'),
>                          (3, 'Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban'),
>                          (4, 'Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire'),
>                          (5, 'Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix'),
>                          (6, 'Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince'),
>                          (7, 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 1'),
>                          (8, 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 2');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 17 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT   B.BOOK_ID, S.SERIES_ID, S.SERIES, B.BOOK, SB.NUMBER_BOOK_IN_SERIES
> FROM     BOOKS B
> JOIN     SERIES_BOOKS SB
> ON       SB.BOOK_ID = B.BOOK_ID
> JOIN     SERIES S
> ON       S.SERIES_ID = SB.SERIES_ID
> WHERE    S.SERIES_ID = 1
> ORDER BY SB.SERIES_ID, SB.BOOK_ID, SB.NUMBER_BOOK_IN_SERIES;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> BOOK_ID | SERIES_ID | SERIES       | BOOK                                            | NUMBER_BOOK_IN_SERIES
> ------: | --------: | :----------- | :---------------------------------------------- | --------------------:
>       1 |         1 | Harry Potter | Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone        |                     1
>       2 |         1 | Harry Potter | Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets         |                     2
>       3 |         1 | Harry Potter | Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban        |                     3
>       4 |         1 | Harry Potter | Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire             |                     4
>       5 |         1 | Harry Potter | Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix       |                     5
>       6 |         1 | Harry Potter | Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince          |                     6
>       7 |         1 | Harry Potter | Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 1   |                     7
>       8 |         1 | Harry Potter | Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 2   |                     8
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e88191260645beb77f750662a0bab800)*